# Solaris 9 projects (resource management)

Tags: solaris

I'm trying to get projects working in solaris 9 (SPARC), so I can limit some users memory usage.

From what I've read, and from what I recall in solaris 10, I should be able to just

1. Create a group (prodsupt), and make this the users default group
2. Create a project called "group.prodsupt"
3. limit the resource in the group.

I've done this, however my user still is not getting limited resources

```
> grep prodsupt /etc/group
prodsupt::6011:
> grep prodsupt /etc/project
group.prodsupt:100:Production Support Project:::process.max-address-space=(privileged.16777216.deny)
```

This should limit anyone with the prodsupt as their default, to about 16mb of address space, however, if I login as a user in this group

```
> id -p
id=1055(mwatson) gid=6011(prodsupt) projid=100(group.prodsupt)
> prctl -n process.max-address-space $$
3084:   zsh
process.max-address-space                [ lowerable deny no-local-action ]
   18446744073709551615 system     deny           [ max ]
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was typo's in the permissions.

```
group.prodsupt:100:Production Support Project:::process.max-address-space=(privileged.16777216.deny)
```

should have been

```
group.prodsupt:100:Production Support Project:::process.max-address-space=(privileged,16777216,deny)
```

This fixed the problem.